Why does there seem to be nothing behind my shower wall tiles?
I live in a large building built in 1929.  My shower still has the original subway tiles, although I suppose I wouldn't know if some of them had been removed and replaced with identical tiles.  Many of the tiles sound hollow when I tap on them.
The grout between the tiles is failing in places and when I started cleaning out the crumbling grout with a snap-off box cutter, I discovered that there were multiple spots where I could just stick the two-inch-long blade all the way into the gap and wiggle it around in empty space.
The gaps between the tiles are too narrow to see through.  (The tiles are so close together that they touch in places, and there the old grout was just in the groove formed by the tiles' beveling.)  However, by poking around I discovered that only the vertical gaps ever lead to empty space.  Are the tiles attached to horizontal rails running along the seams between rows?  Or is the no-horizontal-gaps thing a coincidence and the tiles are directly attached to a wide-spaced wire lath?
I have never heard of tiled walls being built like that, but I only have experience with much newer construction.  Can someone explain how exactly my bathroom wall was built, and why?  Is there anything unusual I need to do in order to fix these holes?  Whatever I put in them will be the only thing keeping water from just flowing directly into the wall cavity.


There is something behind the wall tiles otherwise they would fall down.  What exactly is there is speculation until a wall is opened and it can be seen.  You have tiles that are self-spacing. They have small ribs or bumps on the edges that keep them evenly spaced.  What you can do is remove any loose grout and regrout with an un-sanded grout. If any wall or part of it is soft when pushed, then the damage from water has already been done and the wall must be torn down and appropriate repairs done.

I don't know much about the tiling method used in this bathroom wall. The tiles were thicker than modern tiles and the adhesive bed was much thicker.  As you can see, I was using something a little heavier than a box cutter but it does look like there were some spaces around the edges and corners where I might have had exactly your result had I tried.  Whatever this technique was, it was 40 or 50 years old, rock solid, the grout held up well and the studs were bone dry.  Maybe the grout was redone at some point but still, it held up well.  So I can't say "spaces bad" as one would using modern tile and modern techniques.  Maybe someone with experience tiling this way can chime in.
Maybe this is your situation.  Maybe not.  If your tile job has held up almost 100 years, and you don't have leaks or rot around or below this area, it's not the grout that's holding things together.  If now's not the time for a gut job, you can grind out and replace the grout and (almost) certainly live with it for a while longer.


wow how thick is the thinset on the scratch coat?

@FreshCodemonger  the backing mortar in the wire mesh was about 3/4" and the adhesive layer was about 1".  That's from memory, I didn't measure.  I guess it's not "thinset", in fact I think thinset is called that because it's not this.

haha - good point.  thickset it is !

That's ooooold school.

Thank you!  That picture is entirely consistent with what I'm seeing in my own bathroom.

Could be glaze-faced structural (hollow) tiles or glaze-faced bricks. The former in particular were pretty common at the time. The building of the wall and the tiling done in one operation. They were an inexpensive option at the time - now they appear to live at the premium priced end of the spectrum (at least in the USA - other places structural tile seems to have remained in fashion and so it may be more common/affordable.)
An example, no affiliation: https://elginbutler.com/product-lines/structural-glazed-tile/
As for repairing your tile, clean out the loose grout, squeegee in new grout, clean the surface at the appropriate point in the process per the grout instructions, move on with life.
